# C++ parameter about Tu and Tv in D3DLVERTEX

Tags: c++, vb.net, vector, graphics

I know there are bunch parameter such as x,y,z,specular,color and those parameters which are Tu and Tv in D3DLVERTEX.

What are Tu and Tv? How do we get those value? For example, if we want get normal value from a vertex just calculate cross product of the vertex. Thus, it let us know which that surface pointing to. How about to get Tu and Tv? 
Any detail explanation I will appreciate!! Thanks!

Comment: Is the downvote suggesting me to ask in cs,stackechange instead of here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tu` and `Tv` are **[texture coordinates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206245(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

If your vertices [have an associated texture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174461(v=vs.85).aspx), the texture coordinates map the vertex to a location on that texture.

Comment: So it does not have any relation with x,y,z, does it? And is it possible to not having a vertex texture by set Tu and Tv equals 0? Sorry I am still newbie in 3d computer graphic.

Comment: @Marfin.F it has no relation to the spacial positioning of the vertex.  You are free to ignore those values until you know that you need to use them.

Comment: I see. Thank you sir.